# Hide Hamburger Menu On Specific Page (Front Page/Home Page)

Tags: php, functions, menus, css, navigation

[TheHamburgerCollection.com](http://thehamburgercollection.com/)

My hamburger menu is working correctly on all other pages - I just don't want it to display on the home page, where it's visible at 768px and below.

footer.php is where the menu is located:

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive-menu">
    <?php
        if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
        wp_nav_menu();  
        } 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that I've told it not to display the nav menu on the front page (also the home page), and it's doing this correctly - but how do I do the same thing to the hamburger menu?

I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.internetkultur.at/simple-hamburger-drop-down-menu-with-css-and-jquery/) to create my hamburger menu. If I try to copy the if statement that's telling the browser to display the Nav Menu on all other pages besides the Front Page / Home Page and then paste it just before the div with a class and id `"menu-btn"`, I get a syntax error:

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
    <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    ?>

    <div class="responsive-menu">
    <?php
        if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
        wp_nav_menu();  
        } 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to hide the hamburger menu on a specific page with CSS, or if I do need to use PHP or JS, where should I place the function / what function should I use?

Thank you!

Comment: use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-specific-menu-items/ it allows you to select menu items page wise.

Comment: Do you know if allows you to select whether or not to display a hamburger menu, though?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a syntax error because you forgot to close off your first if. Also, you need to close off the first php block.

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) { ?>
    <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <?php } // <-- You forgot to put this in ?>

    <div class="responsive-menu">
    <?php
        if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
        wp_nav_menu();  
        } 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adjusted footer.php to match exactly what you suggested but still getting syntax/parse error - see homepage: http://thehamburgercollection.com/

Comment: I got rid of the PHP just for now, but this was the error message it was showing: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home2/sduff2/public_html/thehamburgercollection.com/wp-content/themes/thehamburgercollection/footer.php on line 34.

My full code for footer.php can be found here: http://pastebin.com/knLswPVp